# Dynamic filter function for ngFor

Tags: typescript, date, filter, angular7, ngfor

I'm using Angular 7 with Typescript and trying to create a date filter for list. The list may be very large. I have read a lot and I found the Pipe solution. The problem is that when I change the filter arguments the ngFor doesn't refresh, and also I have read the Pipe isn't good for very long lists.

My Html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of sessions | callback: filterByDate" (click)="view(x)">
```

My ts:

```
private filterByDate = (session: Session) => {
    if (this.fromDateFilter && this.fromDateFilter > session.Date) {
      return false;
    }
    if (this.toDateFilter && this.toDateFilter < session.Date) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

The pipe class:

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'callback',
    pure: false
})
export class CallbackPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], callback: (item: any) => boolean): any {
        if (!items || !callback) {
            return items;
        }
        return items.filter(item => callback(item));
    }
}
```

I have angular DatePicker that changes the 'this.fromDateFilter' and 'this.toDateFilter' parameters. In angular 1.6 it was very easy. Every time I change the filter function, it was executed. Here nothing happens.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your Component definition?

Comment: What about put in the ngFor directly the filtered list? (and keep the original list in another var), Observe fromDateFilter from changes or trigger the filter event when the date is modified.